# How can you set the ProcessStrategy for a File or RemoteFile endpoint without using the registry

Tags: apache-camel

I have a `Routebuilder` class with `PollEnrich` endpoint that is set through a `String` field. In the `routbuilder` I want to add a custom File, FTP or SFTP `ProcessStrategy` to the endpoint without using the registry - i.e. by adding `&processStrategy=#customProcessStrategyName` to the string URI. This would require the caller of the `Routebuilder` class to setup the Strategy in advance, and I want to do it in the class itself.

It would be easy if I had the endpoint as a Endpoint object, in which case I could call the `setProcessStrategy` method.

How can I get or create the `Endpoint` object before it is used in a `pollenrich` or from, use the `Endpoint` object to `setProcessStrategy`, and then only use the `Endpoint` object in the `pollenrich` or from, instead of the more common string.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Endpoint programmatically with `CamelContext#getEndpoint` method, which reuses or creates new endpoint.

See [CamelContext#getEndpoint javadoc](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html)

> Resolves the given name to an Endpoint of the specified type. If the name has a singleton endpoint registered, then the singleton is returned. Otherwise, a new Endpoint is created and registered in the EndpointRegistry.

And then use this created endpoint with `.pollEnrich().constant(endpoint)`

```
FileEndpoint fileEndpoint = getContext().getEndpoint("file://somewhere", FileEndpoint.class);
fileEndpoint.setProcessStrategy(new Something<>());
from("direct:input")
        .pollEnrich().constant(fileEndpoint)
        .to("log:output");
```

Using Endpoint in from() is simple as `from(fileEndpoint)` using [RouteBuilder#from(Endpoint)](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/RouteBuilder.html#from(org.apache.camel.Endpoint))

Comment: It was the answer I was looking for, unfortunately it turns out I will not be able to use it in my case. The pollenrich needs to poll a single file which is dynamic and I cannot use the headers CamelFileName or CamelOverruleFileName since I want and need to use the paramater useList set to false. That probably means I will need to access the registry.